# Compiler cannot find method name

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, assembly-references

'm making an application for Windows 8 in C# and XAML.

I've defined two classes within a namespace called AppNamespace, and one of these classes takes a three dimensional boolean array within it's constructor:

```
    public class Solver
    {
        // Board is a class also in this namespace but I don't think the issue is 
        //there, so I've omitted it's definition
        private Board current;

        // You can see that the class clearly DOES take a parameter of the same type
        // as the array "content" (which is defined later)
        public Solver (bool[, ,] initial)
        {
            // The parameter is then used to construct a "Board" class within the
            // "Solver" class.
            current = new Board(initial);
        }

        // Several methods within the class
     }
```

So the definition can be seen above.

I've then created a new page on a gridapp called 'NewPage.xaml' and in that page there is are some textboxes which manipulate the values within the array. (There doesn't seem to be an issue here)

Then in 'NewPage.xaml.cs' when the button is clicked, it should create an instance on the class, and then run a method within the class, at the top of the "NewPage.xaml.cs" I define a three dimensional array as seen below,

```
    // Declare the namespace where the class "Solver" is situated
    using App.Classes;

    namespace App
    {
        // So below is the C# part of the page "PuzzleSolver"
        public sealed partial class PuzzleSolver : App.Common.LayoutAwarePage
        { 
            // Create an array called content
            bool[, ,] content = new bool[9, 9, 9];

            public PuzzleSolver()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();

                //Set every cell of the created content array to true
                for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k <= 8; k++)
                        {
                            content[i, j, k] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

      /* There are some methods which change information in the array "Content" based on the
         stuff input into the XAML textboxes on the page. */


      // The below method is invoked when a XAML Button is clicked on the page
      // and I intend it to create a "Solver" object, using the "content" array
      // from this page as a parameter
      private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        // So now I create the and pass in the "content" array
        Solver newSolve = new Solver(content);

        newSolve.Solve();
      }
}
```

The issue is, that the compiler recognises that "className" is a class, but says that it does not have a constructor which takes 1 parameter, and it also says:

> "ProjectName.className does not contain a definition for "method and
>   no extension method "method" accepting a first argument of type
>   ProjectName.className could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or assembly reference"

Can anyone identify where my issue is from this information?

I've edited this to show other namespace declarations, first the declarations on "Solver.xaml.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using App.Classes;
```

Now the declarations on "Solver.xaml":

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="App.Solver"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App"
    xmlns:common="using:App.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="PageName">Solver</x:String>
    </Page.Resources>
```

Comment: I don't see any method() defined in your className definition.  Check that the method you're trying to call exists.

Comment: ´three dimensional boolean array´ - my head hurts ;-)

Comment: @ScottChapman Sorry, yeah I have defined a method, but I left it out cause the class itself is really long and complicated, but I didn't think that the issue would be with the C#, is this likely to be the case then?

Comment: seems pretty clear... from the code you posted, class Solver has a single parameter-less constructor, but in Button_Click_1 you're newing up an instance using a constructor that expects and argument (content)

Comment: But the Solver class does have a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare your instance, you're using `object` as the variable name.

```
className object = new className(content);
object.method();
```

This causes the compiler to get confused, since `object` is a reserved keyword (it always refers to `System.Object`).

You should use a better name.  However, you could use `@` to use the reserved word, if you desire this:

```
className anyNonReservedWord = new className(content);
anyNonReservedWord.method();

// Alternatively
className @object = new className(content);
@object.method();
```

You do not show the declaration of `method` within your code, so that is difficult to decipher, though it's likely due to the same issue.

---

Edit after your edit:

> I've defined two classes within a namespace called AppNamespace

Your `PuzzleSolver` class is in namespace `App`, not `AppNamespace`.  While you don't show your actual namespace for `Solver`, I suspect it's a namespace mismatch.

Comment: Didn't know about the @ thing. I doubt I'll ever use it, but good to know.

Comment: @SystemDown Yeah - that's why I added an answer in addition to Cory's excellent response ;)

Comment: That's my fault, I changed the names of the classes and objects when I loaded the code it.. But I've put the actual class names there now... And I'm confident that the C# is sound, which is why I haven't posted the method definitions.

Comment: In checking your recommendation, I noticed that I'd named the Solver class the same name as the Page class, so it was a stupid mistake on my part. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`object` is a reserved keyword and you can't use it to name variables. Try changing the name:

```
className somethingDifferent = new className(content);
somethingDifferent.method();
```

Also, you should use Pascal casing for class names, and FTLOG, name your class something other than "className".

Comment: I'm guessing that was a poor re-naming for making a question.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the class and object names in the code I posted... but the actual code i'll post now.